# Set value on ttk.Checkbutton from a ttk.ComboBox

Tags: python, tkinter, get

Hi i trying to set data on checkbutton from a combobox list, and then save this on json file. I have this codes from the program and save function.

```js
 def create_odontograma():
        #Odontograma
            global selected_patologias
            global selected_p
            selected_patologias = tk.StringVar()
            patologias = ttk.Combobox(odontograma_frame, textvariable=selected_patologias)
            patologias.grid(row=10,column=37)
            patologias["values"] = ["Caries", "Endodoncia", "Exodoncia", "Corona", "Puente"]
            

            global e18d
            global e18o
            global e18m
            global e18v
            global e18p

            e18d = tk.StringVar()    
            e18o = tk.StringVar()
            e18m = tk.StringVar()
            e18v = tk.StringVar()
            e18p = tk.StringVar()

            elemento18L = ttk.Label(odontograma_frame, text="18")
            elemento18L.grid(column=7, row=1)
            elemento18D = ttk.Checkbutton(odontograma_frame, width=0 ,offvalue='Sano', onvalue=f'{selected_patologias.get()}', variable=e18d)
            elemento18D.grid(column=6, row=3)
            elemento18O = ttk.Checkbutton(odontograma_frame, width=0,offvalue=f'Sano', onvalue=f'{e18o}')
            elemento18O.grid(column=7, row=3, padx= 1)
            elemento18M = ttk.Checkbutton(odontograma_frame, width=0,offvalue=f'Sano', onvalue=f'{e18m}')
            elemento18M.grid(column=8, row=3)
            elemento18V = ttk.Checkbutton(odontograma_frame, width=0,offvalue=f'Sano', onvalue=f'{e18v}')
            elemento18V.grid(column=7, row=2)
            elemento18P = ttk.Checkbutton(odontograma_frame, width=0,offvalue=f'Sano', onvalue=f'{e18p}')
            elemento18P.grid(column=7, row=4)
```

And here is the save function for json file

```js
def guardar():
            pacientes = {}
            pacientes = []

            pacientes.append(
                        {
                        "Nombre y Apellido": nombre.get(),
                        "Enf. Respiratorias" : f"{agreementa.get()}, {enfrespiratorias.get()}",
                        "Enf. Cardiacas" : f"{agreementb.get()}, {enfcardiacas.get()}",
                        "Enf. Alergicas" : f"{agreementc.get()}, {enfalegicas.get()}",
                        "Enf. Autoinmunes" : f"{agreementd.get()}, {enfautoinmunes.get()}",
                        "Enf. Renales" : f"{agreemente.get()}, {enfrenales.get()}",
                        "Cirugias Previas" : f"{agreementf.get()}, {cirugiasprevias.get()}",
                        "Motivo de Consulta" : f"{motivoc.get()}",
                        "18" :f"Palatino: {e18p.get()}, Vestibular: {e18v.get()}, Oclusal: {e18o.get()}, Mesial: {e18m.get()}, Distal: {e18d.get()}"
            
                        }
            )
            verificar = os.path.exists('./grupopacientes')
            if verificar == True:
                fileName = f"C:/Users/diego/Desktop/ProgrmacionPhyton/consultorio/pacientes/grupopacientes/{nombre.get()}.json"
                isarchivo = os.path.isfile(fileName)
                if isarchivo == True:
                    with open(f'grupopacientes/{nombre.get()}.json','w') as document:
                            json.dump(pacientes, document, indent=3)
                            messagebox.showinfo("Informacion","Se ha actualizado el paciente correctamente")
                            print (selected_patologias.get())
                else:
                    with open(f'grupopacientes/{nombre.get()}.json','w') as document:
                            json.dump(pacientes, document, indent=3)
                            messagebox.showinfo("Informacion","Se ha añadido el paciente correctamente")

            else:
                directorio = "grupopacientes"
      
                # Parent Directory path
                parent_dir = "C:/Users/diego/Desktop/ProgrmacionPhyton/consultorio/pacientes"
                
                # Path
                path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directorio)
                
                # Create the directory
                # 'GeeksForGeeks' in
                # '/home / User / Documents'
                os.mkdir(path)
                messagebox.showinfo("Informacion","La Carpeta no existia, se ha creado y se ha añadido el Paciente")
                with open(f'grupopacientes/{nombre.get()}.json','w') as document:
                        json.dump(pacientes, document, indent=3)
                        messagebox.showinfo("Informacion","Se ha añadido el paciente correctamente")
```

I would like to get data from selected_patologias.get() and put in OnValue on checkbutton atributes, then get this "onvalue" and carry to json.

Comment: Why do you think this isn't working? Are you getting an error? Also, can you please reduce the code down to a [mcve]. If you trying to set a checkbutton from a combobox, we don't need much more than one or two checkbuttons, a combobox, and enough code to show how you're trying to link them.

Comment: The app runs without problems on the command windows, but when I see the json file the get of the value from checkbutton is empty. This is the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: This isn't a minimal example because you have multiple labels and checkbuttons, as well as multiple calls to `open`. You also never create a window or call `mainloop`. If the problem isn't with getting the data but rather it's with writing the json, you can remove all of the tkinter code.